# TFS 2017 Query Tasks For a Sprint with expected capacity

Tags: tfs

I would like to create a query that will join a specific team's capacity for a sprint to how many hours they completed in the sprint. I can't generalize it such as  "I expect everyone to put in at least 30 hrs a week". I have a big team were some people are on vacation or working on other projects part time. In the sprint planning we have set this in the capacity. I want to set this query to only tell me for people that didn't meet their min requirements.

Answer (score 0):

TFS work items are not intended to be used as a timer tracker. The intent is to use work items to capture team-level *estimates*, and then track *remaining time* and whether estimates were accurate. Again, this is captured and tracked at the team level, not at the individual contributor level.

As an example, I can have a task that was estimated at 5 hours. A developer working on that task will update it with the amount of time *remaining*, not the amount *worked*. So after an 8 hour day, if they hit a nasty blocker and got stuck for 7 hours, they may update that task to have 4 remaining hours. That doesn't mean they only worked for 1 hour.

I strongly recommend finding an appropriate third-party time tracker instead of trying to force it into a tool that wasn't designed for that purpose. There are several time tracker extensions on the marketplace, although I can't vouch for how good they are since I haven't used them.